# Pandas: Delete Row if Sentence Contains Word from Other Column in Same Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas data frame `df` and I want to `delete the row` if the sentence column `not contain` value from word column in `same row`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': ['I eat chicken', 'I drive car'], 
               'word': ['eat', 'bus']})
```

I want to delete the `I drive car` row because the sentence does not contain a `bus` word, in other words, I want to keep the sentence if the sentence contains a word in word column. I do this, but it returns an error.

```
df[df['sentence'].str.contains(df['word'])]
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For row wise comparison we have to use `DataFrame.apply`:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['word'] in x['sentence'], axis=1)]
```

Or with `zip` and list comprehension:

```
m = [word in sentence for word, sentence in zip(df['word'], df['sentence'])]
df[m]
```

**Output**

```
        sentence word
0  I eat chicken  eat
```